# Query Posts Incorrectly Displaying Tags Archives

Tags: query-posts, tags, archives

When I go to a tag archive ( http://themeforward.com/demo2/tag/n/ for example) ALL the posts on my blog are being displayed, not just the posts with that tag - and I'd like to fix this.

Here's my tag map, click any tag and ALL posts are being pulled http://themeforward.com/demo2/templates/547-2/

Here is how I am querying posts (there is custom code for an options panel to display the number of posts assigned):

```
<?php
$per_page = get_option('to_count_archives');
query_posts("cat=${cat}&posts_per_page=${per_page}&paged=".$paged);
if (have_posts())
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Whenever you set the query arguments for any type of archive(or view) unless you're merging them you're essentially re-defining that type of query. There's no merging in your code, and you've not specified which file the code you have posted is in, but it's a distinct possibility you could be alterating all kinds of queries(but that's impossible to know without details of where your above code is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a tag.php template from a copy of archive.php or category.php, and remove the 'query_posts' line from the code.

Comment: Would there be any reason NOT to remove query_posts from my index.php and archive.php also?

Comment: I don't know the reason why query_posts is in these templates, so I can't comment on your question. you can always make a backup copy of your theme first, and then try to remove it.